# Piping PrintWriter->CipherOutputStream->FileOutputStream

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptedLogger {

private static Date lastLogTime = null;
private static EncryptedLogger instance = null;
private static FileOutputStream fos = null;
private static CipherOutputStream cos = null;
private static PrintWriter writer = null;
private Cipher cipher;
byte[] Key ={(byte) 0x12,(byte) 0x34,0x55,(byte) 0x66,0x67,(byte)0x88,(byte)0x90,0x12,(byte) 0x23,0x45,0x67,(byte)0x89,0x12,0x33,(byte) 0x55,0x74};

public static EncryptedLogger getInstance(){
    if (instance==null) {
        instance = new EncryptedLogger();
    }
    return instance;
}

private EncryptedLogger(){

    class SQLShutdownHook extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            EncryptedLogger.close();
            super.run();
        }
    }

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(Key,"AES");
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sks);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("log.txt"),true);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    writer = new PrintWriter(cos);

    SQLShutdownHook hook = new SQLShutdownHook();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);
}

public synchronized void logSQL(String s){
    if ((lastLogTime==null)||((new Date().getTime() -lastLogTime.getTime())>1000)){
        lastLogTime = new Date();
        writer.printf("-- %1$tm-%1$te-%1$tY %1$tH-%1$tM-%1$tS\n%2$s\n",new Date(),s);   
    }
    else{
        writer.println(s);
    }
}

public synchronized void logComment(String s){
    writer.printf("-- %1$tm-%1$te-%1$tY %1$tH-%1$tM-%1$tS: %2$s\n",new Date(),s);
}

public static void close(){
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("1");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("22");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("33333");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("4900");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("5");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("66666");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("Some test logging statement");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logSQL("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    EncryptedLogger.getInstance().logComment("here is test commentary");
}

}
```

As you see i'm trying to encrypt text entries piping them through PrintWriter->CipherOutputStream->FileOutputStream chain. But when I decrypt result file there are missing bytes. I tried to flush **cos** and **fos** in EncryptedLogger.close() method - same result. Obviously i'm missing something. What is wrong?

**EDIT**: here is decryption code i use. It's not mine, taken from tutorial or something...
And it works fine when using simmilar encryption. But when using my code...

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESDecrypter
{
        Cipher dcipher;

        public AESDecrypter(SecretKey key)
        {

                try
                {
                        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        {
            System.out.println("decrypting");
            try
                {
                        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);
                        int numRead = 0;
                        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                        {
                                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                        }
                        out.close();
                }
                catch (java.io.IOException e)
                {
                }
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                try
                {
                        byte[] keystr ={(byte) 0x12,(byte) 0x34,0x55,(byte) 0x66,0x67,(byte)0x88,(byte)0x90,0x12,(byte) 0x23,0x45,0x67,(byte)0x89,0x12,0x33,(byte) 0x55,0x74};
                        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(keystr,"AES");                        
                        AESDecrypter encrypter = new AESDecrypter(sks);
                        encrypter.decrypt(new FileInputStream("sqllogenc.log"),new FileOutputStream("sqllogdec.log"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

**EDIT2**: when i write directly to **fos** i get this output:

```
-- 04-19-2012 16-17-56
1
22
33333
4900
5
66666 + delay starting 1100
Some test logging statement
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
-- 04-19-2012 16-17-56: here is test commentary
```

and when writing using **cos** and decrypting:

```
-- 04-19-2012 16-22-13
1
22
33333
4900
5
66666 + delay starting 1100
Some test logging statement
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
-- 04-19-2012 16-22-13: here
```

As you see part of the last line is missing including linebreak.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you decrypt it?

Comment: Your output file seems to be called "log.txt".  If you treat it as a text file then you will mess things up.  Encrypted data is **bytes**, not text.  Also ECB mode is not secure, use CTR or CBC mode instead.

Comment: @rossum: see code, tell me if you spot where i messed up. And AES is just fine for my needs.

Comment: What exactly is missing?

Comment: @axtavt: I added output samples to question body

Comment: Just a small advice. Use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Commons IO to copy data between streams.

Comment: @VadimPonomarev: You know, propositions to use alternative lib's, software, etc are not very constructive. I'm looking for error source, not alternative solution.

Comment: @Aleksandr Kravets: AES is not a problem, ECB mode is.  I also note that you are eating an exception in `AESDecrypter.decrypt()`.  You shouldn't do that, it may be where the problem is.  If you are losing the end of the text then first check the cyphertext length to ensure that everything got encrypted, then check that all file streams are flushed and closed so you know there isn't any data still awaiting processing.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Now i understand more in encryption. Hope i'll find some time in near future to read a good book on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same cryptographic transformation (such as `AES/ECB/NoPadding`) at both sides. Also, note that `NoPadding` mode doesn't allow you to pass data of arbitrary size, therefore you need to specify some other kind of padding.

So, you need to construct `Cipher`s as `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")` at both sides.

Also, note the suggestion of rossum about use of `CBC` or `CTR` instead of `ECB`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits.
When you use AES/ECB/NoPadding, you take the responsability of making sure the size of your message is a multiple of the block size.

It probably isn't, so you get less text when you decrypt.

You should use AES/ECB/NoPadding for arbitrary length of text.